# MongoServerSelectionError: read ECONNRESET

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express

MongoServerSelectionError: read ECONNRESET
at EventTarget. (D:\BookStrore\mern_server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:292:34)
at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:807:20)
at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (node:internal/event_target:742:26)
at abortSignal (node:internal/abort_controller:369:10)
at TimeoutController.abort (node:internal/abort_controller:391:5)
at Timeout. (D:\BookStrore\mern_server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:1008:92)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
servers: Map(3) {
'ac-7vqezfw-shard-00-00.bkyxhls.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
'ac-7vqezfw-shard-00-01.bkyxhls.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
'ac-7vqezfw-shard-00-02.bkyxhls.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
},
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: 'atlas-giqhcr-shard-0',
maxElectionId: null,
maxSetVersion: null,
commonWireVersion: 0,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
},
code: undefined,
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {},
[cause]: MongoNetworkError: read ECONNRESET
at connectionFailureError (D:\BookStrore\mern_server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:357:20)
at TLSSocket. (D:\BookStrore\mern_server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:268:44)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
[cause]: Error: read ECONNRESET
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
errno: -4077,
code: 'ECONNRESET',
syscall: 'read'
}
}
}

how can i solve this error

Comment: How are you attempting to connect?